# Everytime I read in through ifstream for a specific input, the input changes, possible int overflow

Tags: c++, io, integer-overflow

Every time I use ifstream for input to my program for large inputs, I get something weird. I have a feeling this has to do with integer overflow, but my program still doesn't work with unsigned long long. Here is a simplified version of my code that still exhibits the error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    ofstream fout ("namenum.out");
    ifstream fin ("namenum.in");
    unsigned long long serial;
    fin >> serial;
    ifstream myReadFile;
    cout << serial << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the strange input (or larger inputs):

```
5747867437
```

Here is the output I get from cout:

```
1452900141
```

I have no idea what is causing this. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: I would put error checking code to make sure that `fin` is valid and `fin >> serial;` was successful. Initializing `serial` to a known number different from what's in the input file might also reveal the problem.

Comment: If you are using `unsigned long long`, then your input is nowhere near large enough to cause an overflow. See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/. Here is an ideone check of your code to be doubly certain: http://ideone.com/9R1atg. As R Sahu mentions, I would check to ensure that `fin` is valid.

Comment: Exactly łike wolfPack88 says, we can't reproduce the issue. The only culprit left is the file.

Comment: What is `myReadFile` doing here?

Comment: There is no testcase here, and nothing inherently wrong with the program as posted. Please employ diligent and precise debugging techniques, even well before you resort to asking for help on the internet!

Answer (score 1):

Here is advice I have hardly given ever before: **always** check your inputs **after** you attempted to read (it feels, I have given this advice only a few thousands times so it is easy to miss). The stream can't predict what you are going to read and make sure it will work:

```
if (fin >> searial) {
    fout << serial << '\n';
}
else {
    std::cerr << "failed to read the value\n";
}
```

Looking at your code, I'd be about 100% certain that either the file failed to open (i.e. the stream is in bad state prior to the attempt to read) or the claimed content isn't in the file.

Comment: `Here is advice I have hardly given ever before` Satire? ;P

Comment: Sarcasm, but they both begin with `Sa`!

Comment: @ThePhD: [ehm, no....](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarcasm)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the number you supplied is certainly within the limit of unsigned long long. 
Second, using >> for unsigned long long requires C++ 11 support. C++0x supports unsigned long.

I copied your code and made a file called "namenum.in", typed "5747867437" into "namenum.in" using UTF8 encoding.

Then the output is exactly 5747867437.